# gulp-uglify doesn`t work

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-uglify

I want task 'js' takes .js(& not .min.js) files in directory, uglify that & put them in the same directory with suffix: '.min', but it doesn`t work with many files in directory, my task:

```
gulp.task('js', function(cb) {
    pump([
            gulp.src(['js/*.js', '!js/*.min.js']),
            uglify(),
            rename({suffix: '.min'}),
            gulp.dest('js/signup/' + pathDist)
        ],
            cb
        );
 });
```

& my 'watch' task:

```
gulp.task('watch', ['js'], function() {
    gulp.watch(['js/*.js', '!js/*.min.js'], ['js']);
});
```

gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp            = require('gulp'), // Подключаем Gulp
    cssnano         = require('gulp-cssnano'), // Подключаем пакет для минификации CSS
    concat          = require('gulp-concat'), // Подключаем gulp-concat (для конкатенации файлов)
    rename          = require('gulp-rename'), // Подключаем библиотеку для переименования файлов
    uglify          = require('gulp-uglifyjs'), // Подключаем gulp-uglifyjs (для сжатия JS)
    del             = require('del'), // Подключаем библиотеку для удаления файлов и папок
    imagemin        = require('gulp-imagemin'), // Подключаем библиотеку для работы с изображениями
    pngquant        = require('imagemin-pngquant'), // Подключаем библиотеку для работы с png
    autoprefixer    = require('gulp-autoprefixer'), // Подключаем библиотеку для автоматического добавления префиксов
    cache           = require('gulp-cache'), // Подключаем библиотеку кеширования
    svgmin          = require('gulp-svgmin'), //Подключаем svgmin
    open            = require('gulp-open'), // Подключаем библиотеку открытия файлов
    bulkSass        = require('gulp-sass-bulk-import'), // импорт путей в Sass
    pump            = require('pump'),
    sass            = require('gulp-sass'); //Подключаем Sass пакет
```

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "pump": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-cache": "^0.4.5",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-cssnano": "^2.1.2",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^3.0.3",
    "gulp-open": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-sass-bulk-import": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp-svgmin": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-uglifyjs": "^0.6.2",
    "imagemin-pngquant": "^5.0.0"
  }
```

directory has 5 files .js, 5 files .min.js & 1 .php;
Task takes the first file .js in directory, work with it & stops...
How can i work with many files in directory?

Comment: This doesn't explain your problem, but there's a mistake in your glob: to exclude the .min.js files, you need `!js/*.min.js` (`!js/.min.js` will just exclude a file titled ".min.js")

Comment: Some info missing here: have you installed and `require`d pump, gulp-uglify, and gulp-rename? What's logging in the console? (if pump is working, it should give you a detailed error message)

Comment: This mistake i made here, sorry.. but my code is clear with this mistake

Comment: console doesn`t give any error, task works with the first js file and stops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble is `gulp-uglifyjs` uglifies *and* automatically minifies - so all your js files are being processed, but only one (concatenated) file is output. The one generated file gets the same name as the first source file, so it looks at first like only the first file has been processed.

For this reason, `gulp-uglifyjs` [has been deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglifyjs): *"This plugin has been blacklisted as it relies on Uglify to concat the files instead of using [`gulp-concat`](https://github.com/contra/gulp-concat), which breaks the 'It should do one thing' paradigm."*

`gulp-uglifyjs` does work. But if you want to make sure the uglified files are output separately, use `gulp-uglify`. I bet you already know how to do this, but I'll explain in case it helps other people

1. via the command line, change your package.json so you're using `gulp-uglify`:

```
$ cd your-main-project-directory
$ npm uninstall -S gulp-uglifyjs
$ npm install -S gulp-uglify
```

2. in your gulpfile.js, define the "uglify" `var` as `uglify = require('gulp-uglify')` instead of `uglify = require('gulp-uglifyjs')`